# To find the equation of motion in $q$ co-ordinate when Hamiltonian is given and to find the set of Canonical Co-ordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

[image]

With the help of derivative of Hamiltonian with respect to momentum co-ordinate, derivative of position co-ordinate is found but still there is p in the question. How to eliminate that?

Comment: Have you tried to look for the equation of motion for $p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General recipe:

- Hamilton's equations give $\dot{p},\,\dot{q}$ as functions of $p,\,q$.
- Differentiate $\dot{q}$ to get $\ddot{q}$ by the chain rule.
- Rearrange the formula for $\dot{q}$ to give $p$ as a function of $q,\,\dot{q}$.
- Use that to rewrite $\dot{p}$, then $\ddot{q}$.